# setLayoutParams overriding setGravity for layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this section in my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView></TextView>
        <TextView></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My objective is to set the gravity of the items inside the linearLayout and then to add a margin to the whole LinearLayout programmatically.

This is what I have:

```
linearLayout_textBackground.setGravity(gravity); //where gravity is the int of the desired gravity

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
linearLayout_textBackground.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
linearLayout_textBackground.requestLayout();
```

I would like to set the margin in using `layoutParams` but when I run the above code, I notice that my gravity value had been reset. However, if I comment out `linearLayout_textBackground.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`, my gravity value are set correctly.

Why is the gravity resetting after I setLayoutParams to my layout?

Comment: Set gravity after setLayoutParams

Comment: Tried it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @M.Saad Lakhan's answer, I noticed that I was creating a new reference of the parameters. So what I ended up doing is getting the actual params of the layout:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
                    linearLayout_textBackground.getLayoutParams();
```

This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

You are creating new reference for your layout parameters the one you mention here will change the others not mentioned will be changed to default of android. If you want to change gravity then you need to change it after creating new params like:

Use this:

```
linearLayout_textBackground.setGravity(gravity);
```

after this:

```
linearLayout_textBackground.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

or define your layout gravity in defining layoutParams.

But the recommended way of setting your gravity is inside your xml as follows:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

then you dont need to do this :

```
linearLayout_textBackground.setGravity(gravity);
```

Comment: I have to set the gravity programmatically, but thanks to your first point I found a solution so here's a vote. I'll post the solution in a bit. Thanks!